# "Blocked by an extension", unable to manually change the setting anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With the chrome.contentSetting API from Chrome Extensions API, you can change the allow/block/ask state of let's say notification for a website. But the problem I can see now is that it disables the configurable-ness of the setting, for some reason, saying "Blocked by an extension" instead of showing a toggle icon button.

e.g. When I do this:

```js
chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set({
        'primaryPattern': "*://*.twitter.com/*",
        "setting": 'block',    
    },
        details => {
          console.log(details)
        })
```

It becomes something like this below, grayed out the selection, unable to manually toggle them anymore.

[image]

[image]

Is this a bug, or a feature? Is it possible to workaround this problem?

Comment: I think it's the specs.
By the way, Proxy setting by extension is the same.

Comment: It is the intended behavior. There's no workaround.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I revert/unset/reset them? Restarting the browser? Removing the extension? or not possible unless initializing the whole browser profile?

Comment: Either remove the extension or use chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set.